# How to make cell format of 'MMM DD' in xlswriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm stuck in this problem of formatting a cell to date in xlswriter.
The thing is the date is 07/02/2021 and the below image is the result of a manual cell format in excel file which is the correct thing.

[image]

While these are the codes I wrote to imitate it.

```
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import date, datetime

def Test():
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    date_string = "2021-07-02"
    datex = datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)
    number = datetime.timestamp(datex)

    formatx = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'MMM DD'})
    worksheet.write('A1', number, formatx) 

    workbook.close()
```

But the result is not even close:

[image]

I wanted to imitate a format of 'MMM DD' in excel file that if you look at the 'VALUEs BAR'  it is '07/02/2021' and if you look at the 'EXCEL ROW DATA' it is 'July 02'.

But the codes I wrote have the result of these:

- 'VALUEs BAR': '10/22/ -5025'
- 'EXCEL ROW DATA': 'Oct 22'

When I clearly set the right date in the variable 'date_string'. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the line `number = datetime.timestamp(datex)`, remove it:

```
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import date, datetime

def Test():
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    date_string = "2021-07-02"
    datex = datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)

    formatx = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'MMM DD'})
    worksheet.write('A1', datex, formatx) 

    workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image: xlsx_date]

Comment: oh my gad!! I tried worksheet.write('A1', date_string, formatx) but it didn't work, turns out only this is needed datex = datetime.fromisoformat(date_string). tf, why didn't I tried that. tsk, anyway I focused on number = datetime.timestamp(datex) bc everywhere I look, they needed converted date to number to format cell as date. tsk. thanks man! much appreciated!! God bless!

Comment: sir @Sabil, if u don't mind. can you help me out again? pls.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142349/how-to-fix-nginx-504-gateway-time-out